# Vue 3: Module '"../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue"' has no exported member

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm

After updating my npm packages, some of the imports from the 'vue' module started showing errors:

> TS2305: Module '"../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue"' has no exported member 'X'

where X is nextTick, onMounted, ref, watch etc.
When serving the project, Vue says it's "failed to compile". WebStorm actually recognizes the exports, suggests them and shows types, but the error is shown regardless. Some exports like computed and defineComponent work just fine.

What I've tried:

- Rollback to the previously used Vue version "3.2.2" > "3.0.11". It makes the abovementioned type errors disappear, but the app stops working entirely, showing lots of `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` errors in console and not rendering the app at all. In the terminal, some new warnings are introduced:
  `"export 'X' (imported as '_X') was not found in 'vue'` where X is createElementBlock, createElementVNode, normalizeClass and normalizeStyle.
- Rollback other dependencies. None of the ones that I tried helped fix the problem, unfortunately.
- Manually declare the entirety of 'vue' module. We can declare the 'vue' module exports in shims-vue.d.ts, and it actually makes the errors disappear, however, this seems like a terrible, time-consuming workaround, so I would opt out for a better solution if possible.

My full list of dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
   "@capacitor/android": "3.0.0",
   "@capacitor/app": "1.0.0",
   "@capacitor/core": "3.0.0",
   "@capacitor/haptics": "1.0.0",
   "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.0.0",
   "@capacitor/push-notifications": "^1.0.3",
   "@google-pay/button-element": "^2.5.0",
   "@ionic-native/core": "^5.34.0",
   "@ionic-native/qr-scanner": "^5.35.0",
   "@ionic-native/vibration": "^5.34.0",
   "@ionic/vue": "^5.4.0",
   "@ionic/vue-router": "^5.4.0",
   "@j-t-mcc/vue3-chartjs": "^1.1.2",
   "chart.js": "^3.4.1",
   "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.0.0",
   "color": "^3.1.3",
   "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "^0.7.3",
   "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
   "cordova-plugin-qrscanner": "^3.0.1",
   "core-js": "^3.6.5",
   "firebase": "^8.6.2",
   "numeral": "^2.0.6",
   "pug": "^3.0.2",
   "pug-plain-loader": "^1.1.0",
   "secure-ls": "^1.2.6",
   "uuid": "^8.3.2",
   "v-cupertino": "^1.2.4",
   "vue": "^3.2.0",
   "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.1",
   "vue-i18n": "^9.1.3",
   "vue-numerals": "^4.0.6",
   "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
   "vuex": "^4.0.1"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@capacitor/cli": "3.0.0",
   "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
   "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
   "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.33.0",
   "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.33.0",
   "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
   "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~4.5.0",
   "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.13",
   "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
   "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
   "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
   "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
   "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-0",
   "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.2",
   "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
   "eslint": "^6.7.2",
   "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
   "stylus": "^0.54.7",
   "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
   "typescript": "~3.9.3",
   "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
 }
```

[Link to reproduce](https://github.com/YourFriendlyEncounter/vue-module-error)

Comment: Remove and reinstall node modules. If the problem persists, please, show where exactly the errors occur.

Comment: @EstusFlask I forgot to mention, I have actually tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and running npm i, but the problem was still there. The error occurs in any file where I try to import certain exports from the 'vue' module, like this: https://imgur.com/a/dHetUBm

Comment: @tony19 The errors appear: in the terminal (https://imgur.com/a/K2QcJnd), when opening the app in the browser (https://imgur.com/a/tC4UFSy) and in Webstorm (https://imgur.com/a/dHetUBm)

Comment: @tony19 sure, I was able to reproduce the error in a new project by installing the same dependencies: https://github.com/YourFriendlyEncounter/vue-module-error

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, in my case, the trick was to update TypeScript from version "3.x.x" to "4.3.5" (other 4.x.x versions should work, too, but I haven't tried them myself).
As to why this is the case, my theory is that some vue-related dependency became incompatible with the 3.x version of TypeScript after the update.

Comment: thanks for the fix! this creates a constraint loop for me as I’m using ts-jest to test which complains loudly if made to run with Typescript versions 4 and up. I’d like to open an issue with Vue but like you I have no idea which part of the build has the actual culprit.

Answer (score 3):

That named exports from composition API are unavailable means that `vue` is Vue 2 at some place which has only default export. Since Vue 3 is in `dependencies` and both lock file and `node_modules` were refreshed, this means that Vue 2 is nested dependency of some direct dependency.

The problem needs to be investigated in lock file. It shows that `@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest@4.5.13` depends on `vue-jest@3` which depends on `vue@2`.

A possible solution is to upgrade `@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest` to the latest version, `next`. The same likely applies to other `@vue/cli-*` packages because they have matching versions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I actually found a solution that worked for me! I've looked through the package-lock again, tried updating some dependencies, and as it turns out, the trick was to update TypeScript from version "3.*.*" to "4.3.5". It's confusing, as the 3.x version worked flawlessly before, so my best guess would be that Vue, or some other Vue-related dependency suddenly became incompatible with the 3.x version of TS after the update...

Comment: I was getting the same error and upgrading TypeScript worked for me too @VladimirDeev Thank you. This was driving me crazy

Comment: @VladimirDeev If another solution worked for you, consider posting an answer, this may help other users.

Answer (score 0):

The version of TypeScript needs to be at least 4.3.5. In my case, it doesnt work with 4.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when using pnpm, it was caused by `preserveSymLinks` in the `compilerOptions` in my `tsconfig.json`. Setting it to false removed the errors.